# FFMPEG can not open display error for :1

Tags: ffmpeg

i am using Xvfb for starting X server on display 1 and x11vnc is also set for -display :1 along with fluxbox as window manager on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS like using below commands

```
sudo -i -u ubuntu Xvfb :1 +extension GLX -screen 0 1440x1080x16 -ac
sudo -i -u ubuntu DISPLAY=:1 fluxbox
sudo -i -u ubuntu x11vnc -forever -display :1
```

and when I run command:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1440x1080  -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :1.0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast sample.mp4
```

it runs, however when i execute programmatically through processbuilder i see that in output buffer stream log file as :1: Invalid argument and doesn't start recording,

Command sent to processBuilder is like below:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegLocation,
                                "-video_size", "1440x1080x16",                                
                                "-f", "x11grab",
                                "-i", ":1",
                                "-c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast",
                                "-framerate","25",
                                outputfilepath());
```

-FYI I have tried setting environmental variable as export `DISPLAY=:1`, but still the same error and also do I need to set the `DISPLAY=:1`, since i am setting up display number when I start Xvfb? This used to work using avconv on older version of Ubuntu but I am stuck on display issue for ffmpeg, anyone has idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Changing the `video_size` to 1440x1080 made it work.